# Oracle Sql: Checking the value of the database field before updating

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sql-update

I need to `update` a field of a table in the `Merge Into` statement and what I am doing is something like this

```
MERGE INTO A_TABLE a
USING (ANOTHER_TABLE b)
ON (SOME_PK)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
SET a.field = b.field
WHERE a.field != b.field
```

My question is about the last line which I check if these values are `equal or not`. And I can claim that there might be only `%2 difference` between those tables. In this case, what do I lose or win with the `WHERE` clause? Maybe oracle has some optimization in the behind for this cases where the updated field is the same with the value that will be set.

Comment: There is no problem leaving the statement in . . . assuming neither the old nor new value is `null`.

Comment: Please, remove one of your comments. I know there is no problem, I have dbUnit test which certifies this. I am asking what are advantages or disadvantages.

Comment: @Erdiİzgi iki durumdaki `explain plan` dan gelen, `cost` değerlerine bakmıştınız değil mi Erdi bey?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan We can't use local language here. But if you can make cost evaluation between execution plans, that would be also quite nice. I just want to know even if the values are the same, oracle accomplish the update operation. Otherwise, we all know updating is much slower than reading the field.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do yo lose or win compared to what? In any case, EXPLAIN PLAN your queries and check how they behave

Comment: Well lets say, there are 1M entries in one table A and 1M in another table B. The table B needs to be updated based on table A. So this query checks the latest data in the table A and, if there is change, it updates table B. The question is, I can accomplish this with WHERE clause or without it. Without WHERE statement I am having 1M updates, with it I have 1M checks + 20K updates. I am asking which one is better.

Comment: Doesn't Oracle allow to add move `a.field != b.field` into `ON` as additional condition?

Comment: Unfortunately Oracle doesn't allow to modify the fields that you put into the ON clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is, I can accomplish this with WHERE clause or without it. Without WHERE statement I am having 1M updates, with it I have 1M checks + 20K updates. I am asking which one is better.

In my opinion `1M checks + 20K updates` is better. Reasons:

1) Update rows that you need to update, there is no point of making identity operation `A => A`

2) If you have trigger on that table you may end up in troubles.

- Updating `LAST_UPDATE` date (for every call of merge it will look like entire table has changed)
- Inserting to history table (lots of duplicates)

3) You may have materialized view on top of that table with automatic refresh

4) Additional overhead on updating indexes/checking foreign keys